# How to change my android app id

Tags: android, replace, rename

I want to change the app ID (eg. com.kenz.myapp.app to be  com.lionz.myapp2.app)

I tried to replace all IDs with a new one but I get this error

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.kenz.myapp.app/com.lionz.myapp2.app.login }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.kenz.myapp.app/com.lionz.myapp2.app.login} does not exist.
```

Comment: funny of you **but this is not an error** :D, Its just a message from the console that the activity is being started

Comment: `I tried to replace all IDs` So you replaced all ID in the manifest **AND** renamed the `src` and `gen` paths?

Comment: sorry i missed to copy the error part

Comment: HI Frank, I changed it in the manifest but not sure where is the src and gen you are talking about

Comment: I changed it everywhere in the app in the src and all other folders,

Comment: If you're using eclipse, right-click the project, select `Android Tools`, then `Rename Application Package`. If you're using Android Studio, find the equivalent tool.

Comment: i use android studio but could not find similar option